# Trying to extract certain keys out of a JSON file containing tweet data

Tags: python, json, twitter

The code I'm trying to get to work is as follows:

```
import json

json_file = 'stream.txt'
open_file = open(json_file, "r")

for line in open_file:    
    each_tweet = json.loads(line.strip())
    if 'text' in each_tweet:
        print(each_tweet['id'])
        print(each_tweet['text'])

        hashtags = []
        for tag in each_tweet['entities']['hashtags']:
            hashtags.append(tag['text'])
        print(hashtags)
```

and I am using the following JSON file as an example of the format that the end full JSON file will be using (data retrieved through twitter API):

https://pastebin.com/SKz6Hgvn

However I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

While this seems like a pretty simple error I can't seem to find a way to remedy it.

Any help would be a appreciated, I'm pretty rusty at coding haha

Comment: You can't parse JSON line by line. You have to parse the whole file at once.

Comment: seems like the file itself needs some work based on you not being able to read() it

Comment: As @KlausD. mentions, you have to load this entire file. See how the very first character is `{` (and it's alone on that line)? That's hint number one that the entire response is JSON. Your given file parse strategy would be OK if the general file were `.txt` with each line being its own, complete JSON object, but this is not the case.